# How to create login page to Twitter via Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, twitter

I'm trying to create Twitter app with using "twitter4j.jar" and need to create login page but there is a small problem; we cannot use user name and password to login.It's need **"consumer key & consumer secret"** because of I cannot solve how to get this keys for users to be able to login.

***I know I need to make it like this :***

```
        final String CONSUMER_KEY = "HHrGLrxxxxxxxxxxxk4jh534j";

        final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "1588987572-WJOKl3jsRkfxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        final String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "qgioo3BhLTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET));`
```

But cannot apply it there in my app for users :

```
JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("User Name : ");

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password : ");

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{    
            String userName = textField.getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
            Twitter twitter = new Twitter(userName, password);//there I'm getting this error "Cannot instantiate the type Twitter"
            twitter.verifyCredentials();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're logged in!");
        }catch (TwitterException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!");
        }
        }
    });
```

All answers acceptable.Thanks....

Comment: Have a look at JavaFX and it's webkit engine  (WebView) - that would be a lot easier to obtain required tokens using OAuth with it.
If using browser is absolutely impossible, you can try [pin-based auth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based)

Comment: Thanks for replay but I'm trying to make it in java swing.I'm sure there is a method to do.